# 2 Ansible task with Stat and include_vars

Tags: ansible, stat

wondering if anyone can help us with this.

The end goal is to refresh the variables back into the play from a YAML file which was generated previously if the file exists.

I'm using stat to check if the files exist and this works - 'name: Registering if file exists'. If i debug filecheck i can see the 2 entries in the dataset.

Next im trying to reload the vars from the file *-final-dataset-file-1* if the file exists using the when condition - *filecheck.stat.exists*

```
- name: Registering if file exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ inventory_dir }}/host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname }}/final-dataset-{{ item }}.yml"
  loop:
    - file-1
    - file-2
  register: filecheck

- name: IOS - Refreshing final-dataset variables generated by the above tasks in order to service any subsequent tasks
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ inventory_dir }}/host_vars/{{ inventory_hostname }}/final-dataset-{{ item }}.yml"
  loop:
    - file-1
    - file-2
  when: filecheck.stat.exists
```

This is the error i'm seeing

```
fatal: [router]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'filecheck.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (filecheck.stat.exists): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/roles/roles_nane/tasks/report.yml': line 94, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: IOS - Refreshing final-dataset variables generated by the above tasks in order to service any subsequent tasks\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Its like we need to loop through filecheck for each file/item and match these against the files that are a part of the include_vars items but i'm not sure how to do this.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Let's clarify the logic of the workflow. `include_vars` works on the controller's filesystem only. Then, searching files (`stat`) makes sense on localhost only as well. It seems you're looking for files on the remote host (uk-brs-cr01). These files can't be included on the controller (localhost).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The files are in a local inventory on my local machine in host_vars. The include_vars works when i remove the file checking from the task for files that are found but errors when the files dont exist, hence why i'm trying to get this working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the results from the previous task e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars: "{{ item.stat.path }}"
      loop: "{{ filecheck.results }}"
      when: item.stat.exists
```